# Counting over aggregated columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have the yellow table shown below, and I'm trying to get the blue table, which aggregates columns B:F by value, and then counts the number of 'x' symbols for each row value of column A.

Is there some basic SQL/array magic formula to get this, please? There must be.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this new functions formula**

```
=BYROW(B2:4, LAMBDA(v, COUNTIF(v, "=x")))
```

[image]

Used:
[**`BYROW`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en), [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en), [**`COUNTIF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)
`v` is the array_or_range

### Update

```
={ A2:A4, BYROW(B2:4, LAMBDA(vv, COUNTIF(vv, "=x")))}
```

[image]

### For fun

[image]

### Update 02

```
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({
              QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A1:4<>"x",A1:4,1)), 
                               " Select * Where Col1 is not null ", 1)}, 
                               " Select (Col1),sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4) Group by Col1 ", 1)))
```

[image]